# How to show contents inside a tab?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a form with three tabs.Now the tabs are created and i am able to switch between them but can not figure out how to display contents inside a tab

I have tried writing markup tags like h1 in between  but nothing is shown on the output.

```
export class Stackreact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: '1' }
    }

    handle_change = (value) => {
        this.setState({ value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={(e, v) => { this.handle_change(v) }} indicatorColor="primary"
                    textColor="primary" centered>
                    <Tab value='1' label='BASIC DETAILS'><h1>First Tab</h1></Tab>
                    <Tab value='2' label='CONTACT DETAILS'><h1>Second Tab</h1></Tab>
                    <Tab value='3' label='MORE DETAILS'><h1>Third tab</h1></Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want the contents of h1 tags to be displayed in their respective tabs. Please help.Also i am new to this language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working a lot I have come up with this solution which is working fine.

```
render() {
        let content_array = [<h1>First Tab</h1>, <h1>Second Tab</h1>, <h1>Third Tab</h1>];
        return (
            <div>
                <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={(e, v) => { this.handle_change(v) }} indicatorColor="primary"
                    textColor="primary" centered>
                    <Tab value='1' label='BASIC DETAILS'></Tab>
                    <Tab value='2' label='CONTACT DETAILS'></Tab>
                    <Tab value='3' label='MORE DETAILS'></Tab>
                </Tabs>
                <Paper>
                    {content_array[this.state.value - 1]}
                </Paper>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: This cuts through the unneeded complexity in most of the Material UI tab examples, and shows just how simple it is - this really helps.

Comment: What if there are more elements instead of just one `h1`  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use  components like this:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
```

official link : [Tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/)

Comment: In this example I do not understand what {...a11yProps(i)} is?

Comment: @Bhaumik Bhatt
 i just copied it form the official website here is it: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Comment: This is just a copy of the official `material-ui` official docs, so you could put the link in there and it would be better.

Comment: Yes i checked the official site first but i did not understand that code and i still do not. Is there any other solution or can anyone explain this solution?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt If you look at the official link you will see function a11yProps() defined.

It is line 34 here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwilt?file=/demo.js:922-931

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt: I, too, struggled with the name "a11yProps". I finally found it. It derives from the "accessibility project" (https://www.a11yproject.com/) -- "accessibility" is "a", eleven characters, "y". Hence "a11y". I offer this as a canonical example of destroying code readability in favor of misguided desire for brevity. Comment continued on next entry ...

Comment: The name "accessibilityProps" immediately conveys the purpose of the variable to the programmer reading the code for the first (or even hundredth) time. Replacing this with "a11yProps" very effectively obscures that purpose. The candid comments from Alberto Perez and Steven McConnon demonstrate the extreme opacity of the result -- competent programmers who copy code they don't understand purely because it's there.

Comment: @TomStambaugh Yes! I found out the meaning of "a11yProps" from your comment on this post. In modern times, we don't need to limit our code lines to 70 characters. Just use the word you mean, people! Not some obscure or domain-specific abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TabView and TabPanel from primereact

```
<TabView>
   <TabPanel>
     <h1>First Tab</h1>
   <TabPanel />
   <TabPanel>
     <h1>Second Tab</h1>
   <TabPanel />
<TabView />
```

You can research on your own on the props accepted by TabView and TabPanel

Comment: Where it needs to be declared?Because when i tried this it says TabView and TabPanel is not defined

Comment: Yeah, because he is talking about two components from another library, that is this one: https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/tabview

Comment: It could work but i need it to be done using material UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to see the content but you've defined it in the wrong place, [here](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#tabs) you have an example of how to use `Tabs` and `Tab`, because you need to define the data that you want inside of each `Tab` outside the `Tabs` component (`Tab` in meant to be used as a self-closing tag).

Comment: Yes but i do not understand why function TabPanel  is there and what does it do?

Comment: `<TabPanel />` is a functional component defined by the people of `material-ui` in order to hold each item of each `<Tab />`. They're using the `value` to know witch content to show, I meant, if you click the `<Tab />` with the `value` of `two` you should see the proper content (You could check this behavior in the `hidden` prop of `<TabPanel />`) base on the `index`. You could, instead of the `<TabPanel>` you could use whichever component you want to hold the values, you only need to hide the others base on the value (`hidden={value !== index}`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest answer using hooks inspired by the accepted answer.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
..
const [tabState, setTabState] = useState(1);
...
  const handleTabs = (value) => {
    setTabState(value);
    return;
   }

let tabs_array = [<>{variable_with_contents_tab_1}</>, <>{tab_2_contents}</>];
```

Then in the render, you can provide the tab ui

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={tabState}
        onChange={(event, value) => { handleTabs(value) }} 
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        centered
      >
        <Tab value={1} label='Tab1'>
        </Tab>
        <Tab value={2} label="Tab2" />
      </Tabs>
    </Paper>
    <Paper>
        {tabs_array[tabState-1]}
    </Paper>
```